# Java Strings and non-ASCII input from keyboard

Tags: java, string, non-ascii-characters, keyboard-input

So I am trying to take non-ASCII text from the keyboard (`System.in`), Chinese characters for example, and place this text into a `String` object. But I've been having some trouble in doing so. My first attempt used a `Scanner` object:

```
try(Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8"))
{
    System.out.println("Enter text to search for (case sensitive):");
    String searchKey = keyboard.nextLine();
    ...
```

If the user enters non-ASCII text through the keyboard, like for example 狂浪逆襲包, `searchKey` will be filled with garbage. The literal content of `searchKey` becomes "?????" (no quotes, so it's filled with the '?' character). Doing something like:

```
byte[] strBytes = searchKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

shows that all elements in `strBytes` equal to `0x3f`, which is the ASCII code for '?'. I have also tried using reader streams:

```
try(BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8")))
{
    System.out.println("Enter text to search for (case sensitive):");
    String searchKey = keyboard.readLine();
    ...
```

But with this I get the exact same result as when using Scanner. Byte streams don't change anything either:

```
try(DataInputStream keyboard = new DataInputStream(System.in))
{
    System.out.println("Enter text to search for (case sensitive):");
    String searchKey = keyboard.readLine();
    ...
```

I read that `System.console()` might help, but that returns `null` when running under an IDE environment such as NetBeans. What is there left to try? All I need my program to do is to accept non-ASCII text from the keyboard and store this input as a `String` object.

Comment: Try `try(Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-16"))`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Using UTF-16 I am unable to get the `Scanner` to recognize I've ended the line when I hit enter, so the program just keeps on waiting forever for more input.